# In a small dissertation text of 3 or 4 pages, is it possible to divide the text into sections and/or subchapters?

Tags: writing, methodology

I'm going to do a public contest whose proof is a dissertation text. To better organize ideas and present them clearly, I intend to divide them into a few sections. However, if they reject the text for having divisions, what academic and bibliographical basis can I use to justify this method? Is there any basis for this?

Comment: Can you ask them first if that is OK?

Comment: The document that regulates the public examination only informs that it is a dissertation text. And getting in touch is not an easy task. The question above is precisely to file an appeal if the text is not accepted.

Comment: Do they describe "appeals" as an option? If they won't answer questions, it seems unlikely they will consider appeals.

Comment: There is a target date for appels only.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* certainly divide a short report into sections; if you need an *"academic and bibliographical basis"* for defending your choice, any bibliographic database will provide you with a vast choice of papers that fit your description (length <=4 pages, divided in sections).

As for the risk of having your work rejected: it is impossible to provide a complete answer without more context, but I believe it's quite unlikely a work will be rejected in a contest for a minor issue such as improper section division and ordering (unless the contest rules explicitly say otherwise).